# Does the client proxy internally sends its address to the server when making a call?

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF service , with ABC as 'Server_abc'
Now , we created a proxy on the client side and made a call on the server.
My understanding is that the poxy will have the 'Server_abc' of server  and make a connection internally and exucute the code.

The Question is

Does the poxy create a hidden service on the client side and send the Client_abc to the server when a call is made ? other wise how is the response from the server comming to the client for a normal method call (request -response) ?

Also a general doubt

If my service is WCF but if the client is java , the proxy created at the client side will be java_Proxy ,now how is this call coverted and received at the server side .

Answer (score 0):

> Does the poxy create a hidden service
>   on the client side and send the
>   Client_abc to the server when a call
>   is made ? other wise how is the
>   response from the server comming to
>   the client for a normal method call
>   (request -response) ?

The client doesn't create a hidden service, all it does is serialize the request using the specified binding and send it over the wire using low level classes such as [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for example. All this internal plumbings of course are hidden so that you don't have to worry about them and it looks as if you were calling a local function. The server on the other hand does the same serialization and sends the response which the client deserializes back to objects.

> If my service is WCF but if the client
>   is java , the proxy created at the
>   client side will be java_Proxy ,now
>   how is this call coverted and received
>   at the server side.

This will depend on what binding the service is using. For example `basicHttpBinding` is compatible and JAVA clients will have no problems serializing the objects into XML and sending them over the wire to your service. If you the other hand your service uses for example a `netTcpBinding`, only .NET clients will be able to call it. Here's a [comparison between the different bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx).

Comment: "The server on the other hand does the same serialization and sends the response which the client deserializes back to objects"

This what I am not clear - How does the server sends the response t the client ? How the server know the ABC of client to send the response?

Comment: It's **the server** that defines the ABC. When you generate a client proxy it uses this same ABC, so if the client managed to make a successful call to the server then it is using the correct ABC.

Comment: Correct , that is the request part . after processing the request a responce will be send back right . Is response send back to the client or is the response send to the WCFServiceFramwork on the serverside , which will complete and release the call (blocking call).

or is it like the response send to the client ,in which case the client address is required at the server side .

Basically iam not clear about how request response work ?